# Celery 2.5 Starting Multiple workers to handle different types of Job

Tags: heroku, celery

We need to enable background processing in our Heroku App. There are two kinds of Job i.e Job A and Job B.

After creating this we scaled the worked using the command heroku ps:scale worker=1
Both seems to work but issue is if we queue 100 jobs of type A then one job of type B,
job B waits until all of the jobs of type A has finished. But we want to do it like as follows

Create two workers ie worker A, worker B which will process jobs A and B respectively. While queuing jobs we want to ensure that worker A only handles Job A and worker B only handles Job B. And these workers should execute independently. i.e worker A should not wait for worker B to finish its job and vise versa.

Can we do this in Celery.

Currently I'm looking at the doc in [Routing Tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html). But i'm not sure how to start two separate instance of workers for Job A and Job B.

Please help. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.